# Comparing Array versus Table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

My aim is to load the Worksheets(ws1...wsn) in the WorkbookA to WorkbookB with specific condition.
I have formed an array of worksheets present in WorkbookA.

**Condition:** 
I have a table(tblList) in WorkbookB which lists down the worksheet names that has to be ignored loading (Say I do not want to load ws2,ws4).

```
Set SourceDataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(vSrcFileName)
validationProd = SourceDataWorkbook.Sheets.Count

ReDim arrsNames(validationProd)
For i = 1 To validationProd
sName = ""

If fCheckSheet(SourceDataWorkbook, SourceDataWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name) Then
    sName = SourceDataWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    If Len(Trim(sName)) > 30 Then
    sName = Mid(sName, 1, 29)
End If
    arrsNames(i - 1) = sName
    outputWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=outputWorkbook.Worksheets(i + 3)).Name = _
        sName + "_P"
    SourceDataWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate
Else
    ErrorStatus = "Source Sheet not found "
    msgBoxReturn = MsgBox(ErrorStatus & SourceDataWorkbook.FullName, _
        vbExclamation + vbOKCancel)
    GoTo TheExit:
End If
```

Please help me in achieving the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have a lot of hanging statements (`For Loop` and `If Statements`).
I don't know what you mean by load but if what you want is to copy Worksheets from WorkbookA that is not in the list (table in sheet in WorkbookB), you can try below:

Code in WorksheetB:

```
Dim sourcewb As Workbook, destwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set sourcewb = Workbooks("workbookname") 'or using Open method
Set destwb = ThisWorkbook 'contains your table

For Each ws In sourcewb.Sheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Sheet1.Range("tblList"), 0)) Then
        ws.Copy , destwb.Sheets(destwb.Sheets.Count) 'copy after last sheet
    End If
Next
```

This is assuming you have a table with only 1 column like below:

[image]

If not, you should include the header like below:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Sheet1.Range("tblList[List]"), 0)) Then
```

Note that `Sheet1` is the worksheet codename that contains your table.
It can be replaced with `destwb.Sheets("Sheet1")` or whatever name your sheet have. 
Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate Solution to L42. The abpve question can be implemented by using Dictionary.

> ```
> Public Function ExclutionDict(Table As String) As Dictionary
>
> Dim rngTable As Range
> Dim arr As Variant
> Dim Dict As Dictionary
> Dim Count As Long
> Dim tblIgnoreLoad As String
> Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
> Dim test As String
>
> If Table = "tblIgnoreLoad" Then
> Set lo = ShControl.ListObjects("tblIgnoreLoad")
> Set rngTable = lo.DataBodyRange
>
>     arr = rngTable.Value
>     Set Dict = New Dictionary
>
>     For Count = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
>      If Len(arr(Count, 1)) <> 0 Then
>          Dict.Add arr(Count, 1), Count
>      End If
>     Next Count
> End If
> Set ExclutionDict = Dict
> End Function
> ```

The above function can be executed to match the requirement

> ```
> Dim temp As Dictionary
>     Set temp = ShControl.ExclutionDict("tblIgnoreLoad")
>
>      If temp.Exists(SourceDataWorkbook.Sheets(i).name) Then
>       'Do Nothing
>
>      Else 
>   ' Do you usual copy/load
> end if
> ```

The table is converted into an dictionary and the list is taken as array. A condition is validated to check if the worksheet is present in the dictionary, do nothing; else copy.

Note: Please do not forget to add the reference of Microsoft Scripting Runtime to enable dictionary property.

Thanks.